# I just deleted this code- why is it still rendering the photo?

Tags: image, cakephp, render

http://u.neighborrow.com/users/view/4 (sorry - had the wrong link up there, i had copied a redirect by accident)

```
    <?php if (! empty($user['User']['avatar'])): ?>
        <img src="/images/users/<?php echo $user['User']['avatar']; ?>" width="100" />
    <?php else: ?>
        <img src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/<?= md5(strtolower($user["User"]["email"])); ?>?d=identicon&s=100" border="0" alt="My Avatar! UID:<?=$user["User"]["id"] ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php if($logged_in && $logged_in_user["User"]["id"] == $user["User"]["id"]) { ?>
    <a href="http://en.gravatar.com/">Change Gravatar</a> 
     <br><br> OR <br><br>

    <form action="/users/uploadimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmUploadAvatar" class="form">

        <div style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 25px; overflow: hidden;">
            <input type="button" value="Upload Image" />
            <input type="file" id="fBrowser" name="data[User][avatar]" style="font-size: 50px; width: 120px; opacity: 0; filter:alpha(opacity: 0);  position: relative; top: -40px;; left: -20px;" />
enter code here
```

Comment: ...how can we answer this question if all you're showing us is code that's *not* part of the site, and a site that doesn't have a profile picture on it by default?

Comment: There was a google script showing the wrong page- and it seems the reason was due to the svn not updating not cache but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess: because you still have old page in your browser cache or the picture is rendered by some other code.

PS. I can't see any Gravatar image on http://u.neighborrow.com/requests/create

Answer (score 1):

Cacheing, either CakePHP cacheing or, more likely, browser cacheing.